# How can I save my buddy in Oeduard Rex?

Tags: far-cry-2

In the last part of the [Oeduard Rex mission](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Oeduard_Rex), after accepting your buddy's alternative, you need to go to the [North East Oasis](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Oasis_(North_East)) and go down a cistern to tag the gold. But as soon as you do so, a large firefight breaks out at the surface, and by the time you get back up you are surrounded by almost a dozen enemies on foot. This mission seems very difficult, especially compared to the missions you've been doing up to this point in the game.

Following some advice, in my best attempt I did the following preparations:

- Park a [utility truck](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Utility_Truck) near the cistern entrance so I can use the .50 immediately
- Start some fires around, just before jumping down

With this I managed to complete the mission, but I couldn't save my buddy, who died even before I could jump into the truck.

Has anyone been able to complete this mission without so much trouble? What preparation did you have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy. Many people say it's impossible to save your buddy on this mission. But I say it's possible.

After sending the gold location, save your game. Quickly go up to cover your buddy. Don't let the enemy shoot your buddy. Use your body to cover him/her (if your buddy is wounded or gives the blue flare you must restart because it's already impossible to save him/her), after you finish all enemies with your buddy still alive he/she will say thank you. If he/she is wounded he/she can't be helped (you can't give him/her a med pack and if you leave him/her will die). If he/she gives you a flare you must give him/her 3 medpacks but he/she will still die, but you will got his/her dessert eagle.